# React conditional rendering with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to create the buttons that will change between each component, while one is showing, the rest has to be hidden, how can I do that with the click of the buttons?

```
import Step1 from './steps/Step1'
import Step2 from './steps/Step2'
import Step3 from './steps/Step3'
import Step4 from './steps/Step4'

const Activation = () => {
 return (
  <div className='modal-steps'>
     <Step1 />
     <Step2 />
     <Step3 />
     <Step4 />
  </div>

  <div className='modal-activation'>
     <button className='next-step'> Next </button>
     <button className='return'> Return </button>
  </div>
 )
}
```

For example, step 1 will be the default value to be displayed, I will click on the next button, step 1 will be disabled, step 2 will show it and so on. And if you click the back button, the current step will change to hide and the previous one will be shown.

I've been trying to do this for a few days but I haven't really gotten anywhere..

Comment: If you are open to using a library, then just use a slider library.

Comment: where is the state?

Comment: with use state and condition displaying with a while by example i think you can acheive it

Comment: I know how i can do conditional render with 1 component but with all 4 i really dont know D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my code below, please reply whether my code is working or not. Thanks

```
import {useState} from "react"

const Activation = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(1)

  const handleCountUp = () => {
    if (num < 4) setNum++
  }

  const handleCountDown = () => {
    if (num > 1) setNum--
  }

  return (
    <div className='modal-steps'>
      {num === 1 && <Step1 />}
      {num === 2 && <Step2 />}
      {num === 3 && <Step3 />}
      {num === 4 && <Step4 />}
    </div>

    <div className='modal-activation'>
      <button className='next-step' onClick={handleCountUp}> Next </button>
      <button className='return' onClick={handleCountDown}> Return </button>
    </div
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me friend, I'm finishing my first freelancer, and thanks to your help I'm going to make it. :)

Comment: Are you sure you can inc/dec the state that way? I believe you have to use `setNum(n => n+1)` in place of `setNum++`. The same for decrement.

Comment: Hey, is it working? I just type here, not try in code editor. Good luck for ur freelance!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      {currentState === 1 && <StepOne />}
      {currentState === 2 && <StepTwo />}
      {currentState === 3 && <StepThree />}

      <button onClick={() => setCurrentState(currentState + 1)}>Next </button>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentState(currentState - 1)}>
        Previous{" "}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

function StepOne() {
  return <h1>Step 1 </h1>;
}

function StepTwo() {
  return <h1>Step 2 </h1>;
}
function StepThree() {
  return <h1>Step 3 </h1>;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and help me understand how your code worked and helped me understand how your time worked. =)

Answer (score 0):

> Show conditionally these steps

```
  import {useState} from "react";

 const Activation = () => {
  const [activation,setActivation]=useState(1);

  const increment = () => {
     if(activation === 3){
     setActivation((activation)=>activation=3)
     }
     else setActivation((activation)=>activation+1)
  }
  const decrement = () =>{
  if(activation === 1){
     setActivation((activation)=>activation=1)
  }
  else setActivation((activation)=>activation-1); 
 }
  return ( 
  <div className='modal-steps'>
  {activation ===1 && <Step1 />}
   {activation ===2 && <Step2 />}
  {activation===3 && <Step3 />}
  
  </div>

  <div className='modal-activation'>
    <button className='next-step' onClick={increment}> Next </button>
    <button className='return' onClick={decrement}> Return </button>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: I also appreciate your help, I managed to get a result through your answers. :D

Comment: He directly mutates state setNum++ or setNum-- that is not good practice at all, you can check out the documentation